# Calling index_faces on images in sub folders with in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to extract faces from images using index_faces. Images are in a folder inside the s3 bucket 'wedinjoy-events-images'.

```py
bucket = 'wedinjoy-events-images'
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket) 
try:

        random_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        create_collection(random_id)
        for i, s3_object in enumerate(my_bucket.objects.all()):
        if s3_object.key.startswith("45c48cce2e2d7fbdea1afc51c7c6ad26"):
            path, filename = os.path.split(s3_object.key)
            print (s3_object)
            print (path, filename)
            face_result, unface_result = index_faces(random_id, bucket, 
                                         str(s3_object.key), str(s3_object.key).split("/")[1])

except Exception as e:
         print("It has error", str(e))
         pass
```

I am getting the below error since my image is in a folder inside a bucket and hence it has a forward slash.
sample image_url : https://wedinjoy-events-images.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/45c48cce2e2d7fbdea1afc51c7c6ad26/f2346e354a4e398fdf322956eefe4889

> (ValidationException) when calling the IndexFaces operation: 1
>   validation error detected: Value
>   '`45c48cce2e2d7fbdea1afc51c7c6ad26/7d52f78a8de4a8689e4a803686485d74`' at
>   '`externalImageId`' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy
>   regular expression pattern: `[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-:]+`

Answer (score 0):

From the Boto 3 Docs:

> **ExternalImageId** (*string*) -- The ID you want to assign to all the faces detected in the image.

This is not supposed to be the key of the S3 object, but you have set it to `str(s3_object.key)`. This id cannot contain the backslash character. Check out the docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.index_faces)